# If any php error is returned, direct user to x page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, stripe-payments

I have the following code:

```
$stripChargeValid = true;
try {
 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => $amount,
      'currency' => 'cad',
            'capture' => 'false',

      'description'=> $crs_title

  ));


$charge_json = $charge->__toJSON();
$array = json_decode($charge_json, true);
$chargeID = json_decode($charge_json);
$chargeCapture = $chargeID->id;



} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined
  $stripChargeValid = false;
  $_SESSION["cardError"] = $e->getMessage();

  $location2 = "failedPayment.php";

  echo $location2;

}

if($stripChargeValid){
   //Run your queries.
      $insert_c = "insert into orders (course_title,course_price_final,course_provider,user_email,course_date,course_delivery,order_date,charge_id,card_name,final_coupon,coupon_discount,coupon_name) 
             values ('$crs_title','$course_price_final','$course_provider','$user_email','$course_date1','$course_delivery','$order_date','$chargeCapture','$card_name','$finalCoupon','$couponDiscount','$couponName')";
    $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $insert_c);
$location = "index.php";
echo $location;
}
```

I have the following problem if the charge is valid than no problem, but if the charge is invalid, many times some odd errors will appear:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/%3Cbr%20/%3E%3Cb%3EFatal%20error%3C/b%3E:%20%20Uncaught%20exception%20'Stripe/Error/Card'%20with%20message%20'Your%20card%20has%20expired.'%20in%20C:/xampp/htdocs/test/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php:155Stack%20trace:#0 

C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\stripe\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php(268): Stripe\ApiRequestor-&gt;handleApiError('{\n  &quot;error&quot;: {\n...', 402, Array)#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\stripe\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php(114): Stripe\ApiRequestor-&gt;_interpretResponse('{\n  &quot;error&quot;: {\n...', 402)#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\stripe\stripe-php\lib\ApiResource.php(105): Stripe\ApiRequestor-&gt;request('post', '/v1/customers', Array, Array)#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\stripe\stripe-php\lib\ApiResource.php(137): Stripe\ApiResource::_staticRequest('post', '/v1/customers', Array, NULL)#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\stripe\stripe-php\lib\Customer.php(37): Stripe\ApiResource::_create(Array, NULL)#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\paymentCapture.php(28): Stripe\Customer::create(Array)# in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\stripe\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php</b> on line <b>155</b><br />
```

and hence when this happens no other code gets executed. is there any way to make this more global, where for any php error that occurs, takes the user to the following page:

```
 $location2 = "failedPayment.php";

  echo $location2;
```

Update:

```
try {

$stripChargeValid = true;
try {
 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => $amount,
      'currency' => 'cad',
            'capture' => 'false',

      'description'=> $crs_title

  ));


$charge_json = $charge->__toJSON();
$array = json_decode($charge_json, true);
$chargeID = json_decode($charge_json);
$chargeCapture = $chargeID->id;



} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined
  $stripChargeValid = false;
  $_SESSION["cardError"] = $e->getMessage();

  $location2 = "failedPayment.php";

  echo $location2;

} }
} catch (Exception $e) {
 $location2 = "failedPayment.php";

  echo $location2;
}

if($stripChargeValid){
   //Run your queries.
      $insert_c = "insert into orders (course_title,course_price_final,course_provider,user_email,course_date,course_delivery,order_date,charge_id,card_name,final_coupon,coupon_discount,coupon_name) 
             values ('$crs_title','$course_price_final','$course_provider','$user_email','$course_date1','$course_delivery','$order_date','$chargeCapture','$card_name','$finalCoupon','$couponDiscount','$couponName')";
    $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $insert_c);
$location = "index.php";
echo $location;
}
```

still not working unforunatetly

errors that are returned:

```
 switch ($rcode) {
            case 400:
                if ($code == 'rate_limit') {
                    throw new Error\RateLimit($msg, $param, $rcode, $rbody, $resp);
                }

                // intentional fall-through
            case 404:
                throw new Error\InvalidRequest($msg, $param, $rcode, $rbody, $resp);
            case 401:
                throw new Error\Authentication($msg, $rcode, $rbody, $resp);
            case 402:
                throw new Error\Card($msg, $param, $code, $rcode, $rbody, $resp);
            default:
                throw new Error\Api($msg, $rcode, $rbody, $resp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your error message is confusing to me. Why does it start with a URL and then urlencode() the exception message? Or does it redirect the browser to that URL?

Comment: Anyway, it tells you exactly what's going on and which line to look at. So that should hopefully be enough to fix it.

Comment: this page is called through ajax which is why error is submitted through the url. the problem is that i want to make it more global because when the charge fails the error that it returns is unpredictable this is just an example

Comment: The fix would be to catch the uncaught [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: and how would i do that?

Comment: Click on the word "[Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)". That page should explain everything you need to know about Exceptions.

Comment: i mean within the context of this code since i am already using try and catch

Comment: An uncaught exception error means you are definitely **not** catching it. You must be using try and catch around something else.

Comment: i've added an update under my initial post with your suggestion, its unfortunatetly still not working

Comment: Find out what section of your code is executing `/xampp/htdocs/test/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php` line 155 like the error message says.

Comment: this section try {
 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => $amount,
      'currency' => 'cad',
            'capture' => 'false',

      'description'=> $crs_title

  ));


$charge_json = $charge->__toJSON();
$array = json_decode($charge_json, true);
$chargeID = json_decode($charge_json);
$chargeCapture = $chargeID->id;



}

Comment: Before line 155 add `debug_print_backtrace();` and you should see a comprehensive backtrace of what is happening.

Comment: why you do not a `header("location: $location2"); exit;` direct ? Or I do not understand `If any php error is returned, direct user to x page ?`.

Comment: this function is being run through ajax header won't  work. it just means if there any is error whatsover instead of displaying it in the url, direct the user to this page instead

Comment: Sorry but we can only see php code !

Comment: ive display the error lines in the last section of my initial post, when removed they trigger other error

Answer (score 2):

You might want to do \Exception instead of Exception. Depending on what namespace the file you are executing is in.

Comment: You should specify whether you are talking about the `throw` or the `catch` line.

Comment: I'm saying this potentially he should make this line:
} catch (Exception $e) { to } catch (\Exception $e) {

If the php controller above is executing in a namespace then (unless otherwise specified with "use" at the top) it will look for the Exception object in the current, not global, namespace. This has bitten me before.

Comment: thanks for all of your help. unfortunatetly the issue persist

Comment: I'm not sure this will solve it for you either, but why do you have two try... catch blocks? You can just have one and have to catch statements.

Comment: one tres to catch to see if the charge runs and the other tries to see if any error in the code is return'

Comment: You don't need two trys. You can just put the one catch right after the other.